# $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2020}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \left[(\sin x)^n \cdot (\pi/2-x)^n\right]\,dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Calculate:
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2020}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \left[(\sin x)^n \cdot (\pi/2-x)^n\right]\,dx$$

The idea that I had was to let
$ y=x-\pi/2$ and to substitute it in the integral. But I get to
-$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2020}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \left[(\cos)^n \cdot (y)^n\right]\,dy $ which I do not know how to calculate.

Comment: Prove that $\sup\limits_{0<x<\pi/2}(\pi/2-x)\sin x<1$ and use it for an upper bound.

Comment: Could you detail more please?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ one has $$  \left|\sin(x)\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\right|\le \left|x\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\right| \le \left|\frac{\pi^2}{4^2}\right|< 1. $$
What is $ \lim_{n\to \infty}n^{2020} a^{n}$ for $|a| <1$?